# SICP sqrt NullPointerException

Tags: clojure, nullpointerexception, sicp

I've encountered an unexpected NullPointerException while implementing some beginning SICP code in Clojure. In particular, I want to implement the iterative square root procedure from section 1.1.7.

Here's the code:

```
(defn square [x] (* x x))

(defn abs [x]
  (cond 
    (< x 0) (- x)
    :else x))

(defn average [x y]
  (/ (+ x y) 2))

(defn sqrt
  ([x] (sqrt 1.0 x))
  ([guess x]
    (letfn [(good-enough? [guess]
              (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001))
            (improve [guess]
              (average guess (/ x guess)))]
      (if (good-enough? guess)
        guess
        (recur (improve guess) x)))))
```

This works fine for small enough values, e.g. `(sqrt 16)`. I get a `NullPointerException   clojure.lang.Numbers.lt (Numbers.java:3693)` error for any inputs larger than approximately `(square 2718)`.

Any ideas?

Update with the whole traceback (the previous one is all I get in the repl):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.lt(Numbers.java:3693)
    at sicp_in_clojure.chapter_one$sqrt$good_enough_QMARK___14.invoke(chapter_one.clj:40)
    at sicp_in_clojure.chapter_one$sqrt.invoke(chapter_one.clj:43)
    at sicp_in_clojure.chapter_one$sqrt.invoke(chapter_one.clj:37)
    at sicp_in_clojure.chapter_one$eval19.invoke(chapter_one.clj:48)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:6863)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:282)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:401)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)

Comment: Can you paste the whole traceback?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, it works fine for me, even for larger numbers. What versions of Clojure / Java are you working with?

Comment: I also can't reproduce -- I assumed your square functions is (defn square [x] (* x x)). Copy-pasted the code otherwise.

Comment: Paul: yes, I forgot to post my defn of square; I'll edit that in.

Comment: I'm working with Clojure 1.3.0. java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-10M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant or not, but I thought it worth trying it out using the [LightTable Playground](http://www.chris-granger.com/2012/06/24/its-playtime/) app that lets you see how things are interpreted:

[image: light table demo screenshot of above code]

Have you tried with a recent build, say the new [Clojure 1.4.0](http://clojure.org/downloads) release?

Answer (score 0):

Hey it worked fine for me. I Am using clojure 1.3.0. Following is the terminal output.The code works fine.

```
[user@myhost ~]$ clj 
Clojure 1.3.0
user=> (defn square [x] (* x x))
#'user/square
(defn abs [x]
  (cond 
    (< x 0) (- x)
    :else x))
#'user/abs
(defn average [x y]
  (/ (+ x y) 2))
#'user/average
(defn sqrt
  ([x] (sqrt 1.0 x))
  ([guess x]
    (letfn [(good-enough? [guess]
              (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001))
            (improve [guess]
              (average guess (/ x guess)))]
      (if (good-enough? guess)
        guess
        (recur (improve guess) x)))))
#'user/sqrt
user=> (sqrt 16)
4.000000636692939
user=> (sqrt 2718)
52.134441897781194
user=> (sqrt 3000)
54.77225658092904
```

Comment: user=> (sqrt (square 5000)) gave me 


5000.000000041231

Comment: Fascinating :) The code above works perfectly on Clojure 1.2.1, but I keep getting these NullPointerExceptions with 1.3.0. Very odd.

Comment: My clojure version is 1.3.0 .You can see it in my response! I think it will be due to problem in your clojure installation. Make sure that you are not using the beta release(just incase if there is any bug in beta release)

Comment: By the way, this is my java installation,

java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.3) (ArchLinux-6.b22_1.10.3-1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)